# Scooter 49cc trouble starting at morning

Tags: motorcycle, oil, troubleshooting, scooter, aprilia

I was wondering why my scooter (Aprilia 49cc) is having trouble with starting at morning, To make this easy to understand :
- I only have one shot with start bottom, first attempt, my scooter start, but after 4 sec, it turn off again, even that i'm accelerating.
when i try to start it over again, it's hard and sometimes it never start, untill i let my scooter under the sun to warm up it, then the scooter will start fine.

Comment: It sounds like a dying battery. Do you have a multimeter that you could use to test the battery? Do you have a stand-alone battery charger that uses Mains AC power to charge your battery?

Comment: Does it have a manual choke?

Comment: @Moab, I can not be sure, to be honest, this is my first scooter ever, this problem occur only in morning

Comment: @NitrusInc, Perhaps it's the battery ? I never changed it, but if you think so, i will try to buy new one, but is there any more information about what kind of battery should i use ? and thank you for the help tho

Comment: @MedElkasmi I wouldn't purchase a battery until you have checked it with a meter to determine that it's bad. A relative lifespan for Car batteries is about 3 years. If the battery has a date code on it anywhere, over 5 years, I would suspect it's an issue. You could stop in a local Auto Parts store and see if they sell batteries for it. If so, they'll likely have equipment to test the battery and/or charging system, so you can at least have some data to lean towards it being a bad battery. The other thing I would be concerned about, based on the wording of your post, is moisture.

Comment: @NitrusInc I will follow your instructions about the battery, but if you don't mind, does the spark plug play any role in my condition ? and also i forget to mention that the kick start is having also tourbleshooting at morning, cuz after my first try with start button is failed, i use the kick start, but without any result, in 10 times after, does the kick start need good battery to work ? after all i just give up and let my scooter under the sun to warm, after that, the scooter works like nothing happened :D

Comment: @MedElkasmi Yes. Check the plug out, make sure it's not fouled. It looks like it's a 2-Stroke. Is the gas Pre-Mixed, or do you have a separate tank for the 2-stroke oil?

Comment: @NitrusInc I have separate tank for oil, i put 1L of oil in tank and gas exist in another tank, and it mixed automatically. just i add oil each month, actually my scooter has liquid system cooling.